# The use of the phrase "get to know" in context

Tags: phrase-choice

Let's say say I entered a class room full of studnets whom I don't know. And I want to know what their names are, hobbies etc. Would be the phrase get to know be ok in the context for learning names, hobbies and so on? For example:

> Good morning, guys. I am a new teacher, so let's **get to know** about each outher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just leave out the word "about":

> Good morning, guys. I am a new teacher, so let's get to know each other.